# LINQ to XML - Dynamic Element Select

Tags: c#, xml, linq, csv, linq-to-xml

I am writing an integration program that needs to convert and XML document into a flat file. I have the code below that statically names the elements that should be added to the flat file. What I want to do is be able to pass in some sort of list of element names so this method could be used for different integrations. This list of element names will also change in size. I would like to keep this as a single expression. Any ideas?

```
csv +=
            (from el in xmlDoc.Descendants("customer")
             select
                 String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}{4}",
                     (string)el.Element("customer_num"),
                     (string)el.Element("customer_name"),
                     (string)el.Element("last_pmt_date"),
                     (string)el.Element("last_sale_date"),
                     Environment.NewLine
                 )
            )
            .Aggregate(
                new StringBuilder(),
                (sb, s) => sb.Append(s),
                sb => sb.ToString()
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<string> names = (...)

csv +=
    (from el in xmlDoc.Descendants("customer")
     select String.Join("|", names.Select(x => (string)el.Element(x)))
    )
    .Aggregate(
        new StringBuilder(),
        (sb, s) => sb.AppendLine(s),
        sb => sb.ToString()
    );
```